# Content type exception thrown for xsd validation in elements

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have an element A which can be of simple element as well as complex which gets created dynamically.

sample xml is here :

```
 <A>john</A>

 <A>
    <B>kathy</B>
    <C> bat </C>
 </A>
```

my xsd is like this :

```
        <xsd:element name="A">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                <xsd:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:choice>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
```

But here i am facing an exception which says :

Element 'A' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify mixed content in your type:

```
<xsd:element name="A">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
   <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
       <xsd:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:choice>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

Also it's a bit redundant having a sequence inside a choice. You either want a sequence or not.

Hope that helps.